# Asterisk: Play the last recorded file?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, asterisk-ari, asterisk-ael

As I can see, I can use Asterisk cmd monitor to record the call then use the ControlPlayback to play the recorded file. and the default basename is constructed on the channel name plus a number so How can i playback the last call?
for example: I have 3 call, call1, call2, call3 and the channel is 111, so how i can get the name of last call (call3) to playback?

Comment: This question can't be answered,becuase it just dialplan work and dialplan-depend.

Answer (score 0):

One easy method would be to use a global variable to store the recorded file name.

```
[call]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav)
exten => s,n,Set(GLOBAL(lastcall)=${UNIQUEID})
exten => s,n,Dial(...)

[listen]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(${GLOBAL(lastcall)}.wav)
```

To read more about the GLOBAL() function:

```
asterisk*CLI> core show function GLOBAL

  -= Info about function 'GLOBAL' =-

[Synopsis]
Gets or sets the global variable specified.

[Description]
Set or get the value of a global variable specified in <varname>

[Syntax]
GLOBAL(varname)
```